# Reload table view after http post request

Tags: swift, tableview, httprequest, reload

I have main vc includes tableview. When I open my app it starts the get data from api to show table view. I have an add button on navigation bar. when I click on it alert comes with textfields. then I m sending post request those textfields with save button. when I close app and run back no problem I see on datas on table view. but can't reload automatically.

can anyone help about this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call reload the data once you add the new item

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var data: [DataType] = [] // Replace DataType with the type of your data

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchDataAndReloadTable()
    }
    
    func fetchDataAndReloadTable() {
        // Call your API to fetch data
        // On successful fetch, update your data array and reload the table view
        APIService.fetchData { (fetchedData) in
            self.data = fetchedData
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Show your alert with textfields
        // On pressing the save button in the alert, send the post request
        APIService.sendPostRequest { (success) in
            if success {
                self.fetchDataAndReloadTable()
            } else {
                // Handle error
            }
        }
    }
    
    // ... Your table view data source and delegate methods ...
}
```